# Counter-arguments for the Frankfurt cases

Tags: ethics, free-will, determinism

I am looking for critique or good counter-arguments specifically for the Frankfurt cases.

The Frankfurt cases are in turn:

> counterexamples to the  "principle of alternative possibilities", or
>   PAP, which holds that an agent is morally responsible for an action
>   only if that person could have done otherwise.

The Frankfurt cases tells us that an agent is morally responsible for his actions, even if he could not have done otherwise. Here is one example:

> Donald is a Democrat and is likely to vote for the Democrats; in fact,
>   only in one particular circumstance will he not: that is, if he thinks
>   about the prospects of immediate American defeat in Iraq just prior to
>   voting. Ms White, a representative of the Democratic Party, wants to
>   ensure that Donald votes Democratic, so she secretly plants a device
>   in Donald's head that, if activated, will force him to vote
>   Democratic. Not wishing to reveal her presence unnecessarily, Ms White
>   plans to activate the device only if Donald thinks about the Iraq War
>   prior to voting. As things happen, Donald does not think about Iraq
>   prior to voting, so Ms White thus sees no reason to activate the
>   device, and Donald votes Democratic of his own accord. Apparently,
>   Donald is responsible for voting Democratic although, owing to Ms.
>   White's device, he lacks freedom to do otherwise.

I have problem with this...If determinism is true, then Donald would not be free to choose either way. His intentions, values and so forth are predetermined to begin with. Just like in the example above. Donald is predetermined to act a certain way, but seems to have free will - in other words it is a case of compatibilism. However, why would his ability to free will and intentions matter at all for moral responsibility if he is already predetermined to bring about a certain action?

Comment: Can you please include some evidence that this is not a copy-paste homework question?

Comment: And what evidence would that be? I cannot prove to you that this is not a homework question, and you cannot **know** if it is a homework question or not, no matter what the evidence. For all you know, all questions here may be homework questions - you cannot prove or disprove that. **It is not a homework question**, I am looking for good counter-arguments of the Frankfurt cases because I would like to read about that.

Comment: I will try to change the wording of my question. Also, I will try to include evidence that this is not a homework question.

Comment: @Drux I'm not sure that's a standard we've ever applied here.  I can understand a moral reluctance to do homework help, but in terms of the mission of the site, whether a question is homework or not is irrelevant.

Comment: @ChrisSunami It's relevant for me in that I don't want to spend my time on work that has been assigned to students with the expectation that they should carry it out themselves and learn in the process. Whether you apply different standards is of course up to you. My comment was just that: an expression of my own view.

Comment: @Drux I get that, but I wanted to clarify that is a personal decision, not a Phil SE policy (as far as I know).

Comment: I'd go along with Druxes sentiment on this; having said that I wouldn't have recognised this as a typical question for philosophical pedagogy; I'd take it as 'civil' to admit that a question has been set as an assignment and that one is having trouble with it and where.

Comment: I think the standard for all questions applies to HW questions as well: *demonstrate you did some work on trying to solve it yourself* before dumping it on us.

Comment: There's a reason why vote tampering is a very serious crime and mind control is a priori immoral.